# Crystal oscillator input power

Tags: power, atmega, crystal

I have seen many circuits in which they have connected the crystal oscillator with two capacitors as a clock for the microcontroller like atmega 16A. The first question I want to ask is whether the crystal oscillator with two capacitors provide any frequency or not..If it doesn't then why don't we connect a power to the oscillator before giving it to the microcontroller?

Comment: Muhammad Hamza Farooq - Hi, (a) It is not allowed to significantly change a question after an answer has been provided, as the answer addresses the original question, not the new version. Therefore your edit has been reversed (rolled-back). Please don't do that again. (b) There is a [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires any material copied or adapted from elsewhere into a post on Stack Exchange, to be properly referenced. Your new version of the question included 2 new images which did not include the required references. Please follow that rule and the others in the [help]. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Previous answers to your previous questions should already explain this.

What is connected to the MCU is just the crystal, not a crystal oscillator.

The oscillator circuitry for the crystal is in the MCU and is powered along the MCU.

The crystal, and the caps, they do nothing until connected to an active oscillator circuit that drives the crystal into oscillation.

Only when you combine the crystal, and an oscillation circuit for the crystal, you make a crystal oscillator.

Just like you don't have an RC or LC oscillator without the RC or LC components in a suitable oscillator circuit.